# How to replace ImplicitParams with the 'reflection' package?

Tags: haskell, reflection, typeclass, implicit-parameters

I have an enumeration type, e.g.

```
data MyType = A | B
```

And I want to be able to pass values of this type implicitly to my functions. I can do this using the `ImplicitParams` GHC extension like this:

```
type HasMyType = (?myType :: MyType)

myFun :: HasMyType => String
myFun = case ?myType of
    A -> "Foo"
    B -> "Bar"
```

But I've heard many times that it's better to use the Haskell package [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) for this task. Unfortunately, the `reflection` documentation doesn't explain how to write a similar code using the library. And it's not that straightforward to figure it out.

So, my question is, whether it's possible to use the `reflection` library to implement a similar code and to satisfy the following requirements?

1. Values of `MyType` should be passed implicitly.
2. If the `HasMyType` constraint is not specified, the default value of `MyType` should be taken.
3. It should be possible to override the value passed via the `HasMyType` constraint in a single place, e.g. at the beginning of the application.

Does something like this is possible? Or what would be the closest approximation of this using the `reflection` library?

Answer (score 3):

This answers two ways of implementing question *1.* using [*reflection*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection).

Using `Reifies`:

```hs
type HasMyType :: forall k. k -> Constraint
type HasMyType name = Reifies name MyType

myFun :: HasMyType name => Proxy name -> String
myFun name = case reflect name of
  A -> "Foo"
  B -> "Bar"

-- reify :: MyType -> (forall name. HasMyType name => Proxy name -> res) -> res
>> reify A myFun
"Foo"
>> reify B myFun
"Bar"
>> reify A \name -> myFun name
"Foo"
>> reify B \name -> myFun name
"Bar"
```

Haskell can't abstract over type variables yet `\@name -> ..` so it uses `\(Proxy :: Proxy name) -> ..`.

The `Proxy` can be removed from `myFun` where `name` is supplied with visible type applications, but `reify` still generates a `Proxy` whose name must be "extracted"

```hs
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications #-} ..

myFun :: forall name. HasMyType name => String
myFun = case reflect @name Proxy of
  A -> "Foo"
  B -> "Bar"

>> reify A \(_ :: _ name) -> myFun @name
"Foo"
>> reify B \(_ :: _ name) -> myFun @name
"Bar"
```

---

A simpler option (`Given`) doesn't rely on type-level "names" to distinguish between different dictionaries, therefore it is more dangerous with the following warning:

> You should only give a single value for each type. If multiple instances are in scope, then the behavior is implementation defined.

```hs
type HasMyType :: Constraint
type HasMyType = Given MyType

myFun :: HasMyType => String
myFun = case given of
  A -> "Foo"
  B -> "Bar"

-- give :: MyType -> (HasMyType => res) -> res
>> give A myFun
"Foo"
>> give B myFun
"Bar"
```

Comment: I would go a bit further. `Given` is really only appropriate for singletons or similar: if the type has more than one non-bottom inhabitant, and you might care which one you get, then you shouldn't use `Given`.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how `reify` is supposed to pass non-singleton values _implicitly_. Proxies or type applications are still explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But yeah, looks like I can't use `Given` because I have two values of the type. And `Reifies` is not implicit, I need to either pass `Proxy` or use `TypeApplications` to pass it implicitly. `ImplicitParams` almost solve my problem, but the solution with `ImplicitParams` doesn't work due to a bug in GHC.

Comment: @Shersh, the usual way to get good ergonomics with `reflection` is to tie the `s` type in with a phantom somewhere. There's no way to get the default-unless-overridden behavior you seek, as far as I know.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for your insights! I was hoping that ImplicitParams with the "Global implicit params" technique is able to get the "default-unless-overridden" behaviour, but the approach doesn't work with the optimizations enabled: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/18627

Comment: See Edward Kmett's comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/85nnti/why_not_make_type_class_instances_firstclass/dvzra7i/